# How to invoke IronScheme clr-call with type parameter

Tags: generics, type-parameter, ironscheme

I'm trying to use IronScheme with the Open XML SDK to read an XLSX file.

The Open XML SDK API contains a method, which in C# is written as `worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>()`, where passing the type parameter is helpful to filter the elements of the given type.

How would I translate that to IronScheme so that I can pass the `SheetData` type parameter? I tried the following calls, but they all returned all elements:

```
(clr-call Worksheet Elements sheet)             ; sure, will return all
(clr-call Worksheet (Elements Object) sheet)    ; syntax test -> allowed, but returns all
(clr-call Worksheet (Elements SheetData) sheet) ; sadly this also returns all
```

Thanks in advance, Frank

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'type hint' syntax (which is really a bug as it should be reported as not found).

The generic syntax is:

```
(clr-call Worksheet (Elements #(SheetData)) sheet)
```

You pass generic type parameters in as a vector for methods.

Sadly this is different from specifying generic type parameters for types.

I will put it on a TODO list.

Comment: Thanks leppie - and btw thanks a lot for IronScheme!

The syntax proposed didn't work for me (using the latest pre-compiled release from [https://ironscheme.codeplex.com/releases/view/103028](CodePlex).

Comment: I tested by displaying the worksheet elements w/o type `(clr-call Worksheet Elements sheet)` and with the syntax stated above - same results and both result lists did contain elements of type different from `SheetData`.

If it's a potential release problem I can compile from Github on my own, otherwise I can provide more details how to reproduce - but this would also need an Open XML install.

Comment: @FrankRuben: You can get latest builds here: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/leppie/ironscheme/branch/master (go to FX2 build, then artefacts), but it should not make a difference. I will try repro the generics issue, could be related to inheritance in the OpenXML API.

Comment: Hi leppie, thanks for your ongoing support. As you assumed, updating to the current build (1.0.99-54e877f) did not change the results.

Comment: I already have a workaround by filtering the unwanted instances using `filter`, so I'm fine. Regards, Frank